# Automating the creation of a SQL Server Alias on a Client's desktop

Tags: sql-server, installation, client, alias

Does anyone know how would I go about automating the creation of an alias for a client that uses SQL Server (something you would normally use Sql Server Client Network Utility to do manually)?

Many thanks

Comment: hello?  You have proposed answers to your question ...

Answer (score 1):

The aliases are stored in the registry, so a registry file would do the trick. Some options

- deploy a .reg file for the user to double-click
- use remote registry to create the entry
- in your setup utility, include the register entry
- etc

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base BAT script that I use as a starting point:

```
set DBSERVERALIAS=AliasName
set DBSERVER=RealServerName
rem %windir%\system32\cliconfg.exe
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo /v %DBSERVERALIAS% /t REG_SZ /d "DBMSSOCN,%DBSERVER%" /f
reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo
rem 64-bit support for database alias
rem %windir%\SysWOW64\cliconfig.exe
if /i NOT "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "X86" (
    reg add HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo /v %DBSERVERALIAS% /t REG_SZ /d "DBMSSOCN,%DBSERVER%" /f
    reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use DNS to avoid an alias on each client machine? So if anything changes it's one DNS CNAME change rather then updating every client?

An example here: [One SQL Server Instance, Two Server Names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335193/27535)